# Unable to connect to SQL Server database asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently doing an asp.net mvc project when I'm on my way to create roles I can't connect to my database from the asp.net web application configuration for security

Here is my config

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
             connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DonBoscoDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /> 
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"  
                     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
                     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
                     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
                     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                     passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="SmartTimers" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
                     type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"  
                     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
                     applicationName="SmartTimers" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager" >
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="SqlRoleManager"
                     type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
                     connectionStringName="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
                     applicationName="DonBoscoProjectSite" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I also ran the `aspnet_regsql` but still the error persists.

I am using VS 2015 and SQL Server 2014

Comment: So you post your the username and the password, I can only guess you fat fingered one of the two.

Comment: i comment out that part...... i m sorry i accidentally added it here

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable TCP on the local SQL Server instance.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx